# SQL Report Builder 3.0 LookupSet Function on SharePoint Lists

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, dataset

I have two SharePoint list named city and town. I have created two datasets for each list in SQL Report Builder 3.0. The city dataset has ID and Title columns. Town dataset has ID, City_Id and Title.

[image]

My purpose is showing cityname and it's towns in same row.
I use LookupSet function like this:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!City_ID.Value, Fields!Title.Value,"Town"), ",")
```

But, it gives just blank field. How I can use LookupSet function.
Thanks

Comment: Is my expression true ? (=Join(LookupSet(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!City_ID.Value, Fields!Title.Value,"Town"), ",") )

Answer (score 0):

Fields!ID.Value and Fields!City_ID.Value are not same type. Fields!ID is integer, Fields!City_ID.Value is string. So I re-write my expression like this

```
Join(LookupSet(Fields!ID.Value, CInt(Fields!City_ID.Value), Fields!Title.Value,"Town"), ",")
```